# How to setup GridDB on Windows

Tags: windows, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, griddb

What is the best way to set up GridDB in Windows and use it with Anaconda navigator? What are the steps needed to add GridDB to the Anaconda navigator? Is there an executable file that can be used to run GridDB, or should I use a pip install while running Jupyter notebook?